# Problems with remove checkbox dynamically.

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, checkbox

I have looked all over and found many similar threads, but none of them really answered my question with this specific situation:

I want to, when I create a dynamic Checkbox, and want to remove the specific checkbox and the text by clicking on the trash image. It seems to not work when I want to remove.

[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AdiT/KAALv/18/)

HTML:

```
<input type="text" id="checkBoxName" />
<input type="button" value="ok" id="btnSaveCheckBox" />
```

Jquery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#btnSaveCheckBox').click(function() {
        addCheckbox($('#checkBoxName').val());
        $('#checkBoxName').val("");
    });

});

    function addCheckbox(name) {
       var container = $('#cblist');
       var inputs = container.find('input');
       var id = inputs.length+1;

       $('<input />', { type: 'checkbox', id: 'cb'+id, value: name }).appendTo(container);
       $('<label />', { 'for': 'cb'+id, text: name }).appendTo(container);

       $('<img />', { "src": "/Pages/Images/trashDialog.png", "class": "removeCheckBoxDialog"}).appendTo(container);

            $('.removeCheckBoxDialog').on('click', function (e) {

                $("#cb :checkbox").remove();

            }); 


       $('<br/>').appendTo(container);
    }
```

CSS:

```
.removeCheckBoxDialog {
    margin-left:10%;
    cursor:pointer;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try below **jQuery**:

```
$('#cblist').on('click','.removeCheckBoxDialog', function (e) {            
    $('#'+$(this).prev().attr('for')).remove();
    $(this).next('br').remove().prev().addBack().remove();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4Gbm/1/)

---

The above wasnt clearing the label so i edited it a bit :

```
$('#cblist').on('click','.removeCheckBoxDialog', function (e) {            
    $('#'+$(this).prev().attr('for')).remove();
    $(this).next('br').remove();
    $(this).prev().remove();
    $(this).remove();
});
```

### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Q4Gbm/2/)

Comment: Could I please ask you, how this code work: $('#'+$(this).prev().attr('for')).remove();
    $(this).next('br').remove().prev().addBack().remove();

Comment: @AdiT check the second fiddle.Actually I found that the first fiddle wasn't clearing the label

Comment: In `$('#'+$(this).prev().attr('for')).remove(); ` It gets the value within `for=""` which is actually the id of the previous input:checkbox. So if `for = "cb1"` it removes checkbox with id cb1*(#cb1)*

Comment: If you weren't removing the element , instead applying any style like color or any other property the addBack() can be used : http://api.jquery.com/addback/

Comment: Why do you put the .removeCheckBoxDialog in the on delegate? what dose it mean ?

Comment: If we are adding a click event to static elements then `.click()` is used.But we we are adding click event to dynamic elements then .on is used .In `$('#cblist').on('click','.removeCheckBoxDialog', function (e) { ... });` what it means is add a click event to an element with `class=removeCheckBoxDialog` within container with `id=cblist` .The element containing `class=removeCheckBoxDialog` may already be present or is dynamically added

Answer (score 1):

Add this

```
$("#cb"+id).remove();
    $('label[for=cb'+id+']').hide();
    $(this).nextAll('br').remove();
    $(this).remove();
```

to your `click` function

```
$('.removeCheckBoxDialog').on('click', function (e) {

            $("#cb"+id).remove();
            $('label[for=cb'+id+']').remove();
            $(this).nextAll('br').remove();
            $(this).remove();

        });
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/KAALv/33/)

Comment: the `<br/>` should also be removed.

Comment: It is always better to have the whole line inside a container. Like a div element which would remove the need for a br. Having all components of a single line inside a single div also make the remove function as simple as `$(this).parent().remove();`

Comment: @NevilleNazerane It is another way but i dont think my answer deserve your downvote

Comment: The issue is a br is added and then multipal elements are removed one by one including the br. each is selected in a different way and some have append. On the other hand, simply adding the component into a div will make the function quicker as only one element needs to be removed with a simple selector `$(this).parent`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
 $("#cb"+id).remove();
 $('label[for=cb'+id+']').remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try [this](http://jsfiddle.net/KAALv/35/). I have done the following:

1. Appended a div to contain each of the 3 components
2. I used `var container2 = $("div:last-of-type", container);` to select this div.
3. Finally I simply used `$(this).parent().remove();` To get the parent and remove it.

And also I removed the `<br>` as the div does the job of new line by default.